# CiviCRM menu bar corrupted after installing Shoreditch

Tags: extension, theme, shoreditch

I'm trying out the Shoreditch theme (originally for Mosaico, but it's so much more useable I'd prefer to keep it on by default if possible). I see weird white blocks at each end of the CiviCRM menu bar.

[image: Screenshot of corrupted areas on the CiviCRM Menu]

Is this a bug in the current version of Shoreditch, or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There has been some [work](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.shoreditch/pull/386) going on to support shoreditch for CiviCRM 5.13. The temporary solution(until a new release is available) is to make the Menu colour to white by navigating to CiviCRM >> Administer >> Customize Data and Screens >> Display Preferences. Update the form by changing the 'Menu Color' to white

Cheers

Pradeep

[image]